# convert string to json array

Tags: javascript, json

I get this response from an Ajax request.
Javascript seems to intepret it as a string.
(When I say alert this.responseText, the whole string is shown)

How can i convert it to a javascript object (JSON)?

```
{"response": {
   "success": "The activity has been removed",
   "message": "0"

  }
}
```

I am not using jquery.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object

Comment: using prototype or native javascript?

Comment: The reason might be "http status" code. Check the http status code (via F12 in IE or Firebug in FF) to see if it's 200 (=OK) or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the safest thing in the world, but you can do this:

```
var value = null, txt = this.responseText;
eval("value = (" + txt + ")");
```

It might be a little safer to do:

```
var value = null, txt = this.responseText;
!function(window) { eval("value = (" + txt + ")"); }();
```

but there are still all sorts of potential hacks. You're better off using a library.

Comment: target users are blackberry devices. Most libraries don't work (well or at all) with older BB. I am trying XUI, but have not figured out it's JSON capabilities yet.

Answer (score 16):

If you use jQuery, `JSON.parse(this.responseString);` or `jQuery.parseJSON(this.responseString);` should work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the JSON library?

[json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html)

[source](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)